# No USB 04b4:0307 microphone input after Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, usb, audio

I was very happily using VOIP SIP with Ubuntu 10.04.

Since I upgraded to 12.04, not only has Ekiga become very buggy and inconvenient,
but, the subject matter of this question: the microphone of my various USB phones and devices stopped producing any sound.

Sound preferences (`pavucontrol`) show a flat VU-meter. The problem is almost certainly at the kernel level, more specifically in `snd-usb-audio`. Numerous tests I've made show that it appeared in the kernel versions from Ubuntu 10.10 until now.

My question is not only to find a solution but how to contribute more if none.

For example, could I pick `snd-usb-audio` from 10.04 and install it in 12.04 and how.

Additionally, is it true that this question does not belong [here in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315257/no-usb-04b40307-mike-input-after-10-04) but in here (on Unix & Linux)?

Comment: Bug reports are apparently off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. It is possible that they viewed your question as one. For more clarification, you might want to ask a question on the [Ask Ubuntu meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/ask). Sorry they were rude to you; hopefully you'll have a better experience here.

Comment: Post the output of `uname -r` please.

Comment: They didn't mention bug reports but said 1) that a 12.04 problem is invalid because 10.04 is no longer supported 2) that a problem occurring in Ubuntu  is disregarded if other tests with Mint were made (like not mending your car because you also ride a bike).

Comment: Thanks. 3.5.0-23-generic
As I know (but am not allowed to tell) than no later kernel will work, my personal interest is this:
I see that VirtualBox includes .ko modules for 3.2.0-41 and makes the following transformation:
/lib/modules/3.2.0-41-generic/misc/vboxpci.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-23-generic/kernel/misc/vboxpci.ko
Would it be possible to do that for snd-usb-audio from 10.04 to 12.04 and what are the commands to do it and restore?Otherwise, for the benefit of the community, I can test any bootable ISO one shows me to determine when it happened. Any mistakes due to the size of this SMS box.